# show exec returned value

Tags: php, linux

i am using this code in test.php:

```
    <?php
     $con=mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
     exec("awk commend",$out);
     foreach($out as $line)
     {
       echo $line;
     }
      mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

when i use `php /var/www/html/test.php` it give the result of execution. 
What can I do to show the result in browser?

Comment: when i write http://localhost/test.php it doesn't show any thing!

Comment: First of all, please don't use the old `mysql_` functions (even if you don't seem to actually use them). They are soon to be deprecated and if you're learning anyways, you should learn `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: You're having a typo error at line 1 (`<?[SPACE]php`) Is that on your code?

Comment: Path should be http://locahhost/html/test.php

Comment: @Touki i correct it but it still not giving anything!

Answer (score 0):

The path of the awk program must be invalid. Check if the [file exists](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Answer (score 0):

If awk fails, it will probably write to stderr instead of stdout, and you're only printing stdout.

Try having this instead of what you have now:

```
exec("awk commend 2>&1",$out);
```

This will redirect stderr to stdout, so you should be able to see the error message.

Comment: there is any thing wrong in awk command,if use php command to run the file it give me the right answer.

Comment: @kinana.yasin even if it works command line, that doesn't mean it will always work when you run it through the web server. When you run it with command line, stdout and stderr are shown by default, but with web server you would only see stdout with your current code. Please test.

Comment: @kinana.yasin is this still a problem? gentle reminder to update if this has progressed. the command I've given should've shown what's the problem.